# Bash - what's the difference between reading a variable and directly assigning it?

Tags: bash, variables, scripting

Just out of curiosity- what is the difference in the following..

I have a script and I'm converting from KB to MB. I'm using command substitution to assign variables, but just don't see the difference in assigning them as follows:

```
backup_size=$(echo "$client_kb/1024" | bc -l)
```

&

```
read backup_size < <(echo "$client_kb/1024" | bc -l)
```

What is the need for each way of doing things?

Thanks

Comment: Well the second one involves a disk overhead of creating a temporary file in the file system

Comment: @Inian: Does it? I don't see any when running it under `strace`.

Comment: @choroba: It could be a FIFO or a file under `/dev/fd` - https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: Yes, but /dev/fd doesn't create any real files.

Comment: Here, `read` isn't necessary, but you can do some things with `read` that you can't with a simple assignment, the most prominent example being assigning to two or more names at once: `IFS=, read foo bar < <(echo "1,2")` is the same as `foo=1 bar=2`.

Comment: Note: *command substitution* is portable to all POSIX shells, *process substitution* is a "bashism" and is not portable to all POSIX shells. Just something to consider depending upon your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple value like a number, there's no difference. But try it with values that contain trailing spaces or more than one line:

```
#! /bin/bash
func () {
    printf $'1  2\n3   '
}

command_substitution=$(func)
read process_substitution < <(func)

set -xv
[[ "$command_substitution" == "$process_substitution" ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than what @choroba mentioned. It also has impact on *error handling*. Consider a scenario where you can use the output from `sample_func` only if it returned a successful error code.

```
sample_func() {
    echo "Hello world"
    return 1
}

command_substitution=$(sample_func)
rc=$?
echo "Error: $rc"
echo "command_substitution: $command_substitution"

echo '---'

read process_substitution < <(sample_func)
rc=$?
echo "Error: $rc"
echo "process_substitution: $process_substitution"
```

Ouput:

```
Error: 1
command_substitution: Hello world
---
Error: 0
process_substitution: Hello world
```